# How to prevent shell script injection on my local webpage?

Tags: php, python, shell

I have an openwrt router that I use as a local webserver and I created a webpage to dial USSD on my 3G modem, the script looks like this:

```
<html>
<title>CHECK USSD</title>
<body>
<?php
if($_POST['send']){
    $ussd=$_POST['ussd'];
    exec('ussd.py '.$ussd,$out);
    echo "Result: ".$out[0];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
USSD :<input type="text" autofocus name="ussd" size="14" value="">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Send Ussd">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`ussd.py` is the python script that I use to check USSD. The problem is that when a user tries to input some kind of script in the input box, like: `$(echo "hacked" > /www/index.html)` or `$(rm -fr /root/*)` those scripts get executed as well. So people can easily hack my router. How can I prevent that from happening ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: you should thoroughly validate your user input before piping it into `exec`. use a regular expression. anything that doesn't match a close definition what you want to accept as input should be immediatelly discarded.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Agreed, simply using `escapeshellarg` and thinking that you are done is not safe enough.

Comment: You can put the list of accepted commands in an array and check if it matches any of the accepted ones before running the command inputed

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `escapeshellarg()` so that your string is treated as a single argument.

```
$pattern = '/Some regex that matches your potential inputs/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $ussd)) {
   exec('ussd.py '.escapeshellarg($ussd),$out);
} else {
   //throw error / response to user
}
```

Generally speaking though, executing directly from user input is not considered safe. Hence, find a regex that corresponds to a pattern in your potential input commands, and ensure that it matches before proceeding (You have specified that hardcoded commands are not an option).

Comment: `escapeshellarg($out)` is probably not what you want

Comment: You said ` executing directly from user input is not considered safe.` what's the safest method then?

Comment: Provide the user with a list of predefined options that correspond to parameters of the script. Failing that, an array of accepted parameters with some pattern matching was suggested in another comment.

Comment: Well, since the ussd commands often change, I don't think I can just set pre-defined options like that.

Comment: Do the commands have a pattern / something that they all have in common? If that is the case you can limit the accepted inputs to match the pattern

Comment: No ussd commands keep changing over time, but they usually consist of a bunch of numbers, * and #. No letters.